# Как не делая ap.a абстрактным отключить его срабатывание при переходе в дочерний state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-router

```
.state('ap.a', {
    url: '/a',
    controller: IndexCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'PageCtrl',
    templateProvider: RouteHelpers.templateProviderFactory('ap.a'),
})
.state('ap.a.create', {
    url: '/creatb',
    controller: CreateCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'PageCtrl',
    templateProvider: RouteHelpers.templateProviderFactory('ap.a.create'),
})
```

Первый `state` содержит табличку с данными (список). второй соответственно создает элемент. При переходе в `ap.a.create` родительский `state` также срабатывает загружает данные, которые реально не нужны. Как не делая `ap.a` абстрактным отключить его срабатывание при переходе в дочерний `state`?

P.S. Добавлять еще один `state` а-ля: `ap.a.index` тоже не желательно.

Answer (score 1):

Можно указать другой parent. Но, если честно, не очень понятна ваша мотивация.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views